# In Google sheets, using a script, can I replace all the functions in cells with the plain text or number values they've calculated?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets. The first sheet is an order form where you can enter customer details and their order summary.

On another sheet, these data are copied to relevant cells in a picking slip and a tax invoice, just using preformatted cells, and simple functions, ie:

='Order Submission Form'!E9

And then that cell is populated with the Customers name.

However, I then have a script which duplicates that spreadsheet, deletes all except the sheet with the picking slip and tax invoice, then turns it into a PDF. All of that code works fine, except that deleting all the redundant sheets also breaks the cell references, and so I end up with the picking slip and tax invoice just populated with #REF! in all the cells.

This is the complete code that I'm using to generate the PDF. I know I copied at least some of it from somewhere else, but I don't remember where I originally got it.

There is a section which seems to suggest it replaces the cell values with text to avoid broken references, but it does not seem to work, and it gives an error: "Incorrect Range height: Was 59 but should be 999 (Line 22, file createPDF)"

```
function checkSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = "Picking Slips";
  var folderID = "1gp3dqdwMSXzwQ6gzhctbQk5ODnpBOHB_"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var orderNumber = ss.getRange("'Picking Slips'!G4").getValue()
  var pdfName = "Picking Slip # "+ orderNumber + " - " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  //Dump the contents of the picking slip into order history
  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  //repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);      

  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
  destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
  }
  }


  //save to pdf
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);

    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+sourceSpreadsheet.getId()+'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4'                           // paper size legal / letter / A4
    + '&portrait=false'                     // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true'                        // fit to page width, false for actual size
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&gid='+sourceSheet.getSheetId();    // the sheet's Id

  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If my understanding for your issue is correct, for example, how about using [``getDisplayValues()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of ``getValues()``? Or, in your script, the endpoint for exporting PDF is prepared. But in the current script, it seems that the endpoint is not used. So how about creating PDF file using this endpoint?

Comment: Read the API docs about `getMax____` and `getLast____`. Then consider that the data you are writing is possibly of different size, so you should probably acquire a range based on its length and width instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the whole sheet and select copy and then paste special > paste values, only you will overwrite every formula in the sheet with its value.

You can script this as follows:

```
var range = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
range.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```